# Parent Directory Nginx

Tags: nginx

Всем добрый день! На сервере настроен листинг одного из каталогов (доступ по паролю) и все работает ок! Вопрос в том, можно ли как-то средствами nginx закрыть доступ к корню сайта (доступ на уровень выше Parent Directory) пользователям, зашедшим в этот каталог? Может, как-то через редирект? (Мысли вслух). 
Вот конфиг:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
# ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/data/181219/certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/data/181219/private.key;

ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

root /home/user/data;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name data.site.com;

if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
     }

location /loc1 {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Hello, please login";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/user/.loc/.htpasswd_vid;

               add_before_body /.html/top.html;
               add_after_body /.html/bot.html;
               autoindex on;
               autoindex_localtime on;
               autoindex_exact_size off;

               sub_filter '<html>' '';
               sub_filter '<head><title>Index of $uri</title></head>' '';
               sub_filter '<body bgcolor="white">' '';
               sub_filter '</body>' '';
               sub_filter '</html>' '';
               sub_filter_once on;

               charset   utf-8;
        }

location ^~ /loc2 {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404
        autoindex on;
        auth_basic "Hello, please login";
        auth_basic_user_file /home/user/.loc/.htpasswd_vid;
        }


location ~ ^/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    deny all;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/home/user/data/:/media:/home/user/fiverr/work";
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-data.site.com.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_hide_header "Cache-Control";
limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
}
    expires max;
    add_header Last-Modified $sent_http_Expires;


location /gui {
              proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
              proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

Comment: А почему вы считаете что он открыт?

Comment: Потому что на него попадаешь без проблем через "Parent directory"

Comment: Конфиг в студию

Comment: Конфиг выложил.

Comment: А теперь с начала. Вы открыли что? Нажали куда? Получили что? Хотели получить что?

Comment: Захожу в /site/loc1 (или /site/loc2) по паролю, получаю листинг файлов, но при нажатии "Parent direcotry"  попадаю в "Parent direcotry" (/site/), а надо чтобы не попадал, т. е. запретить "Parent direcotry",